# Let $f_i : V_i \to V_{i+1}$ with $V_0=V_{n+1}=0$, show that $f_1$ is injective and $f_{n-1}$ surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V_0,...,V_{n-1}$ be finite vector spaces with $V_0=\cdots =
> > V_{n+1}=0$ and let $f_i : V_i\to V_{i+1}$ be linear maps with
>   $\text{im}(f_i)=\ker (f_{i+1})$.  Show that $f_1$ is injective and
>   $f_{n-1}$ surjective

My idea: Since $V_0=0$, we have that $\text{im}(f_1)=0$ since a linear map maps $0\mapsto 0$. So we have $f_1^{-1}(\{0\})=\{0\}$ making it injective. Is that correct and do you have any ideas how to prove that $f_{n-1}$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes quite the same way. Because $V_{n+1}={0}$, one has

$$\forall x\in V_{n}\, f_{n}(x)=0$$

Therefore $\operatorname{im}{f_{n-1}}=\ker{f_{n}}=V_{n}$ and this proves the surjectivity of $f_{n-1}$

Comment: I do not see the interest of putting a full answer here instead of pointing in the right direction. Anyway now my answer is useless.

Comment: You’re absolutely right. Sorry.